# Create Back Button with Storyboards

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I currently have 3 tabs connected to a common UITabBarController. When one of the tabs is selected the user is taken to a UITableView with 3 cells which can be selected. When a cell is selected the user is taken to a new page with a UINavigationBar at the top. My understanding is that the UINavigationBar is supposed to include some sort of back button and I couldn't figure out how to enable it.

In place of the default back button, I dragged a UIButton to the corner and connected it to the 'Show Detail' property of the previous view but when I press the UIButton I am taken to the right UITableView but the tabs are missing for navigation. What am I doing wrong? My segues look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UINavigationController has the back functionality. [How to go back one view in UINavigationController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293155/how-to-go-back-one-view-in-uinavigationcontroller).

[Here](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/06/25/uitabbarcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller-using-interface-builder/) is some old tutorial on how to combine that with a tabbarcontroller. should still be the same principles.

Comment: So is that functionality only available for a UINavigationController? Because when I go to drag one onto my storyboard they come as two views. I only need the second one since I already had my UITableView complete before starting the detailed view and thus I just have a UIViewController with a UINavigationBar on top.

Comment: Well you can always be creative and implement [popping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907518/modal-view-controllers-how-to-display-and-dismiss) of the views yourself, maybe [unwinding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them) is what you want to do

Comment: It turns out the segue unwinding was just what I needed. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! Have a great evening